# How to properly assign a variable a Boolean value and test for it?

Tags: java

I am trying to make class that sets the time using three integer variables for amount of hours, minutes, and seconds, and a fourth Boolean variable to set AM or PM.  I am able to get the three integer variables to work correctly, but I don't know what I am doing wrong regarding the Boolean variable not being assigned or tested correctly.

```
public class Time
{
    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private int second;
    private boolean amPm;

    public Time(int setHour, int setMinute, int setSecond, boolean setAmPm)
    {
        hour = setHour;
        minute = setMinute;
        second = setSecond;
        amPm = setAmPm;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        if (amPm == true)
        {
            String halfDay = "P.M.";
        }
        else
        {
            String halfDay = "A.M.";
        }
        return hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + " " + halfDay + ".";
    }
}
```

Comment: you didn't mention, how you are using this *Time Class*, and how passing the arguments in which scenario?

Comment: Your problem is the scope of the variable ```halfDay```

Comment: Declare `halfDay` outside of the `if`.

Comment: Doing `if(amPm == true)` is useless, you should do `if(amPm)`

Answer (score 3):

You can't use halfDay as it's out of the scope

> In computer programming, the scope of a name binding – an association of a name to an entity, such as a variable – is the region of a computer program where the binding is valid: where the name can be used to refer to the entity. Such a region is referred to as a scope block. In other parts of the program the name may refer to a different entity (it may have a different binding), or to nothing at all (it may be unbound).

In other world, you declare halfDay in the if/else statement, but it disapear once you close the brackets. If you want to use it for your concatenation, you need to change his scope, by declaring it before.

```
public class Time
{
    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private int second;
    private boolean amPm;

    public Time(int setHour, int setMinute, int setSecond, boolean setAmPm)
    {
        hour = setHour;
        minute = setMinute;
        second = setSecond;
        amPm = setAmPm;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String halfDay;
        if (amPm == true)
        {
            halfDay = "P.M.";
        }
        else
        {
            halfDay = "A.M.";
        }
        return hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + " " + halfDay + ".";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue you've come across here is one of scoping: You are initializing the `halfDay` String inside the if/else statement in the `toString()` function, but it needs to be available outside of that to be used in the return statement.

Your objective can be achieved using a [ternary operator](https://www.sitepoint.com/java-ternary-operator/) like so:

```
@Override // Overriding the toString() method from Object
public String toString() {
  return hour + ":" + 
    minute + ":" + 
    second + " " + 
    (amPm ? "P.M" : "A.M") + "."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `boolean` is fine, the `halfDay` variable doesn't have *scope*. Give it scope. Like,

```
public String toString()
{
    String halfDay;
    if (amPm)
    {
        halfDay = "P.M.";
    }
    else
    {
        halfDay = "A.M.";
    }
    return hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + " " + halfDay + ".";
}
```

But, I would prefer to not use such a temporary variable. You could do,

```
public String toString()
{
    if (amPm)
    {
        return hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + " P.M..";
    }
    return hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + " A.M..";
}
```

**or** with a ternary and a formatted `String`. Like

```
public String toString()
{
    return String.format("%d:%d:%d %s.", hour, minute, second, amPm ? "P.M." : "A.M.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplified boolean check and changed scope of halfDay:

```
public Time(int setHour, int setMinute, int setSecond, boolean setAmPm)
    {
        hour = setHour;
        minute = setMinute;
        second = setSecond;
        amPm = setAmPm;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String halfDay = "A.M.";
        if (amPm)
        {
            halfDay = "P.M.";
        }
        return hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + " " + halfDay + ".";
    }
```

Comment: ah! my bad...thanks for the heads up, edited now...

Comment: And upvoted for the less (but not the least, to be honest) verbose solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String toString()
{

    String halfDay = "";
    if (amPm == true)
    {
        halfDay = "P.M.";
    }
    else
    {
        halfDay = "A.M.";
    }
    return hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + " " + halfDay + ".";
}
```

Do this.  Your halfDay variable isn't in the scope of your return.